# Fourier transform in the complex plane

Tags: fourier-transform, quantum-optics, complex-numbers, wigner-transform

I see the following formula when reading a textbook on quantum optics:

$$g(u)=\int f(\alpha)\, e^{\alpha^*u-\alpha u^*} \, \mathrm d^2\alpha,$$

$$f(\alpha)=\frac{1}{\pi^2}\int g(u)\, e^{\alpha u^*-\alpha^*u}\, \mathrm d^2u.$$

The book defines them as 'Fourier transforms in the complex plane.' Are there any proofs or justifications of them?

Comment: Might this question be better suited for [math.SE] as there is no relevant physical context given?

Answer (score 4):

You have $i\Im (\alpha^*u) = \frac{1}{2}(\alpha^*u - u^*\alpha)$ from complex calculus; remember $$z-z^* = (a+ib)-(a-ib) = 2ib.$$ Therefore, the exponent is purely imaginary. The integration element $\mathrm d^2\alpha$ means that you have to integrate over the real part of $\alpha$ *and* over its imaginary part.

Substitute $\alpha = \alpha_R+i\alpha_I,u=u_R+iu_I$ and compute $\Im(\alpha^*u)$. This will give you a two-fold Fourier integral, one is over $\alpha_R$ and another is over $\alpha_I$. The second Fourier integral is the inverse transformation; it can be proven analogously.

Comment: Normally when we do a 2D fourier transform, we only deal with a function of, say, $x$ and $y$. But now $f(\alpha)=f(\alpha_R+i\alpha_i)$. There is an $i$ hanging around. Also is $d^2\alpha=d\alpha_R+i d\alpha_i$? How to change this back to the usual $dxdy$? I don't know how to make these two changes from the original definition of Fourier transform involving only real numbers.

Comment: It is d^2 \alpha = d \alpha_R d \alpha_I

Comment: I'm coming to this very late but I hope I can get a response. If you let $\alpha = x+iy$ and $\omega = \omega_x + i\omega_y$ and substitute those into the usual FT $(x,y) \leftrightarrow (\omega_x,\omega_y)$ you'll get the exponent to be $i(x\omega_x + y\omega_y) \leftrightarrow (i/2)(\alpha\omega^* + \alpha^*\omega)$. So why don't we end up with that, or how do we get to $\alpha^*\omega - \alpha\omega^*$? Thanks for any response you can give.

Answer (score 0):

This is analogous to ordinary Fourier transformation. Bring the expression for $f\left(\alpha\right)$ into the r.h.s. of the equation for $g\left(u\right)$, it goes like

$$
\text{r.h.s.} = \frac{1}{\pi^2}\int\mathrm{d}^2\alpha\ \mathrm{d}^2v\  g\left(v\right) \mathrm{e}^{v^*\alpha - v\alpha^*}\mathrm{e}^{\alpha^*u-\alpha u^*}\\
=\frac{1}{\pi^2}\int\mathrm{d}^2\alpha\ \mathrm{d}^2v\ g\left(v\right)\mathrm{e}^{\alpha^*\left(u-v\right)-\alpha\left(u-v\right)^*}\\
=\int\mathrm{d}^2v\ g\left(v\right)\delta^2\left(u-v\right)\\
=g\left(u\right)
$$
where the integration of the delta-function can be proved in the following way. Denote $\alpha = x+\mathrm{i}y$ and $w=u+\mathrm{i}v$, we have $\mathrm{d}^2\alpha=\mathrm{d}x\ \mathrm{d}y$ and $\alpha^*w - \alpha w^* = 2\mathrm{i}\left(vx-uy\right)$.

$$
\int\mathrm{d}^2\alpha\ \mathrm{e}^{\alpha^*w-\alpha w^*} = \int\mathrm{d}x\ \mathrm{e}^{2\mathrm{i}vx}\cdot\int\mathrm{d}y\ \mathrm{e}^{-2\mathrm{i}uy} = \pi\delta\left(v\right)\cdot\pi\delta\left(u\right) = \pi^2\delta^2\left(w\right).
$$

(which is eqn 3.99 in this textbook.)